# How do you implement a monad promise that is resolved by a clock in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, monads

While watching [Douglas Crokfrod's talk on monads and promises](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=dkZFtimgAcM#t=52m44s) I was interested a question that was asked at 52:40.  How would one implement a watchdog timer with Monads so that a promise could be kept or only live in a pending state for some definable length of time before it's failure functions are called.  Does this pattern have a commonly accepted name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't, Jason.
Looking at Crockford's implementation on GitHub, it doesn't have a suitable hook for that behaviour.

That said, within a typical Promise paradigm, there are more options than what the Crockford code grants.

Look at AJAX libraries. Despite many people not knowing it, a lot of AJAX libraries (including jQuery) will return promises.

To do it within his code, you could hook in a clause which has a timer which `.break`s the promise, based on a time submitted with a promise's argument.

Otherwise, you could do something like:

```
var vow = VOW.make(),

    last_promise = vow.when()
                      .when()
                      .when()
                      .when() /*...*/;


(function () {
    var vow = VOW.make(),
        time_over = false,
        time_limit = 30 * 1000,
        timer_handle,

        success = function (value) {
            if (time_over) { vow["break"]("Time's up!"); }
            else {
                clearInterval(timer_handle);
                vow.keep(value);
            }
        };

    trailing_promise.when(success, /* fail */);

    return vow.promise;

}()).when(/* ... */)
    .when()
    .when();
```

Something like that should work with what's given there, I think.

Personally, after seeing the talk and reading his implementation, I think I prefer promises to keep their linear-queue functions (`done`, `fail` or `success/fail` or `ready/fail` or whatever), but most of the libraries I've seen make the temporal-queue (`when`, `next`, etc) separate from the promise.

So you have two competing queues here, really.  One where you subscribe to an event (like `.addEventListener`: when the action happens, all of the listeners get called at the same time), and one where you subscribe to the eventual-return of the next result (like listening to something which is subscribing to an eventListner).

In Crockford's minimal implementation, it's more like you can only have one listener, and then subscribers listen to the last subscriber of the previous subscriber of the previous...

...and the only way to chain multiple instructions to happen in the same queue would be to cache returns:

```
var level_0 = VOW.make(),
    level_1 = level_0.when(/* ... , ... */),
    level_2 = level_1.when(/* ... , ... */);


level_1.when(/* more stuff */);
level_1.when(/* even more  */);


level_2.when()
       .when()
       .when();


// ...eventually.......

level_0.keep("stuff");
```

Comment: As much as I like my own answer, mine isn't a true monad

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing with jQuery's Deferred methods (which I think is monadic though I can't find a statement), and it looks like this would work (a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3kKBc/)) (this looks too easy)

```
function watchdog(promise, time) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        promise.abort();
    }, time);
};
```

An example of this using the [Ajax test hooks](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html) in JSFiddle:

```
console.log("Waiting 2,000ms for something we think will take 3,000ms to return");
watchdog(
  $.post('/echo/html/', { delay: 3 })
   .done(function() {console.log("Got It!");})
   .fail(function() {console.log('took too long (but I knew that)!');})
   .always(function() {console.log('Cleaning up no matter what');})
  , 2000);

console.log("Waiting 3,000ms for something we think will take 2,000ms to return");
watchdog(
  $.post('/echo/html/', { delay: 2 })
   .done(function() {console.log("Got It (but I knew that)!");})
   .fail(function() {console.log('took too long!');})
   .always(function() {console.log('Cleaning up no matter what');})
  , 3000);
```

This is the log that is produced:

```
Waiting 2,000ms for something we think will take 3,000ms to return
Waiting 3,000ms for something we think will take 2,000ms to return

took too long (but I knew that)!
Cleaning up no matter what
Got It (but I knew that)!
Cleaning up no matter what
```

Comment: This would work because once a promise it kept can't be broken, so if the promise succeeds it goes from "pending" to "kept", if the timeout gets called first it goes from "pending" to "broken".  But again I don't know enough about monads to understand if this is a correct implementation.